# ReactJS - Handle parent event in child event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a react container where I want to capture `mousemove` events. That is pretty straight forward. Further I have a react sub-component rendered by the container where actually the logic for the `mousemove` event handler resides. So I need to pass/delegate the `mousemove` event from the container parent to the child and get the `mousemove` handler of the child invoked. How is that done properly?

I need to capture the mouse event in the container rather than the sub-component because the container is a larger HTML element in the DOM and I need to capture events in that whole area.

The mousemove-handler-logic needs to be in the sub-component as it encapsulates some functionality the container should not be aware of.

The render method of the container:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div data-component="MyContainer"
             onMouseMove={(event) => this.handleMousemove(event)}>
            
            <MySubComponent {// ... give some props here}>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I tried an approach where `MyContainer` sets callback functions for `MySubComponent` to retrieve its DOM Node and register handler with `addEventListener` but that did not work consistently as occasionally the DOM Node got undefined:

```
export default class MyContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};

        this.getContainerRef = this.getContainerRef.bind(this);
    }

    getContainerRef() {
        return this.refs['containerWrap'];
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div data-component="MyContainer"
                 ref="containerWrap"
                 onMouseMove={(event) => this.handleMousemove(event)}>
                
                <MySubComponent getContainerRef={this.getContainerRef} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default class MySubComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        // ... init something
        
        this.handleMousemove = this.handleMousemove.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // add event listener for parent application frame
        let containerDOM = this.props.getContainerRef();
        containerDOM.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMousemove, false);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // remove event listener from parent application frame
        let containerDOM= this.props.getContainerRef();
        containerDOM.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMousemove, false);
    }
    
    handleMousemove(event) {
        // handle the event
    }
    
    // ... more methods
}
```

I also tried to call the `mousemove` event handler in `MySubComponent` directly from `MyContainer` via `this.refs.SubComponent.handleMousemove` but that is regarded to be bad practise in react-redux.

Comment: your question has nothing to do `redux`. Can you have the `onMouseMove` event directly handled by `MySubComponent`? it makes more sense if the logic is completely handled by `MySubComponent`

Comment: Could you give the code of your first approach, so we can understand what went wrong?

Comment: @xiaofan2406: See my edit on the question. I need to capture the event on the large HTML container element rather than on the quite small sub-component.

Comment: @DamienLeroux: I added the code. You can see that I provide a callback function `getContainerRef` to `MySubComponent` where it can retrieve the DOM ref of the container and register the event handlers itself. But when container got unmounted the provided ref always turned undefined and the event handler could not be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working with `refs` should be avoided if possible.

If you want to capture the `onMouseMove` in the parent container I think best is to just pass the relevant properties of the `event` to your child component. When the values change in the parent `componentWillReceiveProps` and `shouldComponentUpdate` in the child component get invoked and you can react to it.

```
class Container extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        mouseX: 0,
        mouseY: 0
      };
    }
  handleMouse(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      mouseX: event.clientX,
      mouseY: event.clientY
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div onMouseMove={(event) => this.handleMouse(event)} className="demo">
        <Child x={this.state.mouseX} y={this.state.mouseY} />
    </div>;
    }
}
```

And your Child component:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.handleMouseMove(nextProps.x, nextProps.y);
  }
  handleMouseMove(x, y) {
    if (x < 150) { // return true to invoke render for some conditions
      // your code
      return true;
    }  
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Child Component</div>;
  }
}
```

However your implementation in the child component will look like. It just has to know about its `props` and nothing about its parent component.

react component lifecycle: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Answer (score 0):

Although your mousemove should be in the subcomponent and your container should use mapDispatchtoProps, like this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onmousemoveAction: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}
```

and in your subcomponent dispatch(onmousemoveAction)

But if you still want to have logic in subcomponent do

```
this.refs.mysubcomponent.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'))
```